# What is a data type mismatch in criteria expression? How to resolve error?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm working on a software development assessment which requires me to create a form in which the user can purchase products. The products purchased are then inputted into a Microsoft Access database.

Here are some images of the form and the database table:

[image: The visual basic form]
 [image: tblOrders Design View]

However, when I click "btnOrderProducts", I receive an error in the message box which reads: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." This problem only occurs when cmboxProduct is "iPad Case" which is strange and confuses me.

Below is the code for the visual basic form:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmOrderProduct
    Dim iPadCasePrice As String
    Dim iPad2Price As String
    Dim prod_list As List(Of String)
    Dim Total As Decimal

    Private Sub frmOrderProduct_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Call connection()

        cmboxProduct.Items.Add("iPad Case")
        cmboxProduct.Items.Add("iPad 2")

        iPadCasePrice = "$20.00"
        iPad2Price = "$200.00"


        txtUsername.Text = frmLogin.txtUsername.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddToCart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddToCart.Click

        If cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = "" Or txtQuantity.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please fill out all required fields", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid entered data")
        Else
            ListBoxCart.Items.Add("x" & txtQuantity.Text & " " & cmboxProduct.SelectedItem & " " & txtPriceEach.Text)

            Dim q = Decimal.Parse(txtQuantity.Text)
            Dim p = Decimal.Parse(txtPriceEach.Text.Remove(0, 1)) 'need to remove the $ before parse
            Total += p * q
            txtTotalPrice.Text = String.Format("${0}", Total)


            'txtShoppingCart.AppendText("x" & txtQuantity.Text & " " & Product1 & Environment.NewLine)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtQuantity_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtQuantity.KeyPress

        If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOrderProducts_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOrderProducts.Click

        Dim numberOfItems = ListBoxCart.Items.Count
        For Each item As String In ListBoxCart.Items

            Try

                cm = New OleDbCommand
                With cm
                    .Connection = cn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblOrders ([ProductName],[Quantity],[PriceEach],[TotalPrice],[Username]) VALUES (@ProductName,@Quantity,@PriceEach,@TotalPrice,@Username)"

                    prod_list = item.Split(" ").ToList
                    Dim prod_name = prod_list.ElementAt(1)
                    Dim prod_quantity = Integer.Parse(prod_list.ElementAt(0).Remove(0, 1))
                    Dim price_each = prod_list.ElementAt(2)

                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@ProductName", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, prod_name))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Quantity", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, prod_quantity))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@PriceEach", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, price_each))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TotalPrice", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Total))
                    .Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, txtUsername.Text))
                    prod_list = New List(Of String)

                    cm.Parameters("@ProductName").Value = prod_name
                    cm.Parameters("@Quantity").Value = prod_quantity
                    cm.Parameters("@PriceEach").Value = price_each
                    cm.Parameters("@TotalPrice").Value = Total
                    cm.Parameters("@Username").Value = txtUsername.Text

                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Record saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                    cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = ""
                    txtQuantity.Text = ListBoxCart.Text = ""
                    txtTotalPrice.Text = ""

                    Exit Sub
                End With
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try

        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClearCart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearCart.Click

        ListBoxCart.Items.Clear()
        Total = 0
        txtTotalPrice.Text = String.Empty

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmboxProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmboxProduct.SelectedIndexChanged

        If cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = "iPad Case" Then
            txtPriceEach.Text = iPadCasePrice
        End If

        If cmboxProduct.SelectedItem = "iPad 2" Then
            txtPriceEach.Text = iPad2Price
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much for reading this far if you have. Thank you!! ^_^

Comment: Should this have a  vbscript tag? If you debug, which line does the error occur on?

Comment: Not sure, but if you believe it should I'll chuck it on.

Comment: Actually it shouldn't because this is application based rather than scripting.

Comment: I would look at the parameters that you are inserting. Perhaps one is null?

Comment: You're setting all parameters data-type to `VarChar`. But in the table `PriceEach` and `TotalPrice` are of type `Currency`. I think that's the issue.

Comment: @EthanPayne where Exactly does the Error Apear at which line?

Comment: @MatSnow what should they be set to instead? Currency? Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Moosli the error doesn't appear at a specific line, just a message box when clicking the order products button.

Comment: @EthanPayne then comment out the Try Catch part so you can see where he is getting the Error or Set a Break Point and go step by step through the Code. so you can see what line is throwing the Error

Comment: @EthanPayne Yes, set them to the corresponding datatype of the column you want to insert it to. Furthermore it doesn't make sense to define the price variables as string. They should rather be of type `Decimal`.

Comment: @MatSnow I then get an error stating failed to convert parameter from a string to a decimal. mhm.

Comment: @EthanPayne I already told you two weeks ago to not concatenate strings for the listbox-items and then later split the string to get the price. ;-) The `$` sign before the price is the problem now. As long as you don't basically change the design of your app you will ever and ever run into such issues.

Comment: Sorry @Matsnow I just dont't exaclty understand how your code works hahaha. I'm truly sorry, but I also want to the user to be able to see what's in their cart at the same time :P I don't know >.< I've just gotten so far into it I didn't really want to get rid of it all, it was tough work haha. Thank you for your continued help though :)

Comment: @MatSnow I also don't know how from your code to put it into my database as well which sub to put it under. Sorry I'm kinda new to the more advanced side of programming xD

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you should really rethink the design of your application, because extracting prices from a string that you concatenated before does not make sense.

To answer the question:

This line will extract *"Case"* from your first item and *"2"* from the second item:

```
Dim price_each = prod_list.ElementAt(2)
```

So with the following line you'll get the price-part of the string:

```
Dim price_each = prod_list.ElementAt(3)
```

But that only works until you add a word to the article description like *"iPad 2 64GB"* instead of *"iPad 2"* for example.
Then it will take 64GB instead of the price.
To make this more dynamic you can always take the last item of `prod_list` and remove the $-sign:

```
price_each = prod_list.ElementAt(prod_list.Count - 1).Replace("$"c, "")
```

Also you should set the parameters to the suitable data-type. 
Means `Currency` instead of `VarChar` for `@PriceEach` and `@TotalPrice`.

Comment: Thanks heaps @MatSnow. I'll try it out shortly :) I think I understand now :D

Comment: hey man, I just wanted to thank you so much for your help with all my questions. Is there any way we could have a private chat somewhere so we can discuss what to do to make my program more functional to prevent extraction of prices from a string. I'll be new to this area of programming so some help would be really appreciated and I'd love to talk about it. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome @EthanPayne. Uuuhm, in short: No - nothing personal or something like that, but I'm just not interested in giving private lessons at the moment. :)
But to get better in programming, you can not avoid reading tutorials/books/documentations. Also there's a site on stackexchange for this purpose: Ask it on [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).